# How to get the return value if an R function has an error

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-inverse, singular

I want to test if a matrix is singular or not in R. I tried a function, which is

`is.non.singular.matrix()` in `matrixcalc` package.

However, sometimes, in my case there is a 60*60 matrix generated, the function returns `FALSE`, which means the matrix is singular. But I can still use `solve()` to get the invert of the matrix. Which one should I trust? Is there any other better way to do?

Or, for a singular matrix, `solve()` will return a error message. Is there a way to write a statement, that if `solve()` returns an error, then do something else (for example, add some variations to the diagonal elements). But I don't know how to get the return value of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Test whether `try()` returns an object of class "try-error":

```
 mtx <- matrix(c(1,1,2,2), 2)
 if ( inherits( try( solve(mtx), silent=TRUE),  "try-error")){"oops"} else {solve(mtx)}
[1] "oops"

> if ( inherits( try( solve(mtx), silent=TRUE),  "try-error")){
                                     print("oops"); solve(mtx+ rnorm(4) )
                                    } else {solve(mtx)}
[1] "oops"
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  0.8310745 -1.618425
[2,] -1.0580812  3.050279
```

You could conceivably build this as a recursive function. See:

```
?Recall
```

Comment: Never now the try() function. It's great. Thank you a lot. I will check more about those functions.

Comment: Could you please tell me more about inherits? The R menu is not that easy to follow...

Comment: Yes. It's easy to see by using `class(try(solve(mtx)))`. `inherits(x, "class_name")` is safer to use than `class(x)=="class_name"`